# How to get the latest value from nodes and save it to a variable

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML.  What I am trying to do is get the latest duration into a variable using XSLT.

```
<Root>
<Department name="Test1">
<Duration>N/A</Duration>
</Department>
<Department name="Test2">
<Duration>00:02:33</Duration>
</Department>
<Department name="Test3">
<Duration>00:00:43</Duration>
</Department>
<Department name="Test4">
<Duration>N/A</Duration>
</Department>
<Department name="Test5">
<Duration>00:00:23</Duration>
</Department>
<Department name="Test6">
<Duration>00:05:03</Duration>
</Department>
<Department name="Test7">
<Duration>N/A</Duration>
</Department>
<Department name="Test8">
<Duration>00:01:25</Duration>
</Department>
<Department name="Test9">
<Duration>N/A</Duration>
</Department>
</Root>
```

So, given the above XML, the latest duration should be 00:05:03.

I've tried the following but getting the wrong value.  I am getting N/A.

```
<xsl:variable name="maxDuration">
<xsl:for-each select="/Root/Department/Duration" >
<xsl:sort data-type="text" order="descending" />
<xsl:if test="position()=1">
<xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"N/A" appears in your XML, and alphabetically, "N/A" comes after "00:05:03". ("N" has ASCII value 78, "0" has ASCII value 48)

One solution, would be to just ignore "N/A"

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Root/Department/Duration[. != 'N/A']" >
```